# Prove that $\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}(r · S_{n−1}) = r^{n−1}\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}(S_{n−1})$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Prove that $\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}(r · S^{n−1}) = r^{n−1}\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}(S^{n−1})$

My attempt is :

$\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}(r · S^{n−1})=\int_{rS^{n-1}}1dS=[x=ry]=\int_{(S^{n−1})}r^{n-1}dS=r^{n-1}\operatorname{Vol}_{n−1}( S^{n−1})$

Comment: What are $S^n$, $S_n$ and $\operatorname{Vol}_n$? Why don't you replace $n-1$ by $n$ everywhere? It would look more pleasant.

Comment: I've edited this and $S^n$ is the unit sphere

Comment: What you did is okay, but the non-trivial part is explaining why the surface element transforms with $r^{n-1}$.

Comment: You can always use this [general sphere volume](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball). This may seem silly,  but you can prove this then for extra dimensions, maybe, and use defined expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a full answer but more of a thought,

if we think of $S^{n-1}$ as an $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere, then $rS^{n-1}$ is the same sphere but with radius $r$. Looking at the equation for an $n$ dimensional sphere of radius $r$ we see that it is proportional to $r^n$ which makes sense to conserve units. This can be written as:
$$\text{Vol}_{n-1}(rS^{n-1})\propto r^{n-1}$$
Now we need a constant to make this an equality, and that will be $\text{Vol}_{n-1}(S^{n-1}).$

---

Its much easier to think of it in terms of a cube, lets define an $n$ dimensional cube $C^n$. In this case it is clear that:
$$\text{Vol}_n(C^n)=1\,\,\,\forall n$$
but if we again scale this cube by $r$ in all dimensions, represented by $rC^n$ then the volume will clearly be scaled by $r^n$ so:
$$\text{Vol}_n(rC^n)=r^n\text{Vol}_n(C^n)$$